# SQL query for last 5 years average calculation for each datapoint?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, self-join

```sql
    WITH temp_tbl_2
                 AS (SELECT 
                            state,
                            wk_number,
                            year,
                            maxtemp,
                            Avg(salary)
                              OVER (
                                partition BY state, wk_number
                                ORDER BY wk_number, year rows 4 PRECEDING) AS
                            avg_max_5years
                     FROM   tbl
                     ORDER  BY state,
                               wk_number ASC,
                               year ASC)
            SELECT * FROM  temp_tbl_2
```

QN: Current code-Last 4 and current year records used for avg calculation - Using spark sql to computing the result.
Input columns: STATE, WK_NUMBER, YEAR, MAXTEMP
Calculated Column - avg_value_5years_max

```
Current result - 
STATE   WK_NUMBER   YEAR    MAXTEMP avg_value_5years_max
A         1         2015    21      21
A         1         2016    19.3    20.15
A         1         2017    18      19.43333333
A         1         2018    21.4    19.925
A         1         2019    24.8    20.9
A         1         2020    21.7    21.04
A         1         2021    22.5    21.68
A         1         2022    20.1    22.1



Current Input :

CREATE TABLE tbl (
   state      char(1)
 , wk_number  int
 , year       date
 , maxtemp    decimal(7,2)
 , salary     decimal(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('A',       1,        '2015-01-01',   21)
, ('A',       1,        '2016-01-01',   19.3)
, ('A',       1,        '2018-01-01',   21.4)
, ('A',       1,        '2020-01-01',   21.7)
, ('A',       1,        '2022-01-01',   20.1)
;
```

need to cal 5 year avg considering the missing years -
Expected output

```
    +-------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------
    | state | wk_number | year       | maxtemp | avg_value_5years_max
    +-------+-----------+------------+---------- --------------------
    | A     |         1 | 2015       |   21.00 |  21.00
    | A     |         1 | 2016       |   19.30 |  20.15
    | A     |         1 | 2018       |   21.40 |  20.5666
    | A     |         1 | 2020       |   21.70 |  20.8
    | A     |         1 | 2022       |   20.10 |  21.06666
    +-------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------
can someone help me on this? Thanks
```

Comment: Tag the question with the database and exact version you are using.  It's unlikely you want `year<=5`.  What does that mean?  Maybe you're asking about a difference between two dates.  Add data to the question and the expected result, given that data.  Your current result appears to be the result of your current SQL (the derived column name does not match).  Show the result you would like to generate.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. It is unclear now.

Comment: @LajosArpad - Thanks, updated the qn with more context.

Comment: @JonArmstrong - Thanks! Please check the updated qn.

Comment: I don't understand your expected result.  Why is 2017 missing in the result?  Where is the input data (INSERT statements)?

Comment: You also changed the question to include a "missing years" requirement.  You should NEVER change the basic question like that.  There's no way to evaluate your SQL related to missing years if you don't show the data (INSERT statements).

Comment: @JonArmstrong - 
Assuming the data is from file(contains missing years) which is read through spark dataframe and interacted with sql to perform calculation of new column - avg_value_5years_max(I think inner join works but not sure) , can you please check this now. Hope this is clear :)

Comment: Please provide the exact input data you used to generate the "Current result" and which should lead to the "Expected result".   **Read carefully**:  I'm asking you to provide the `INSERT` statements, just like I did in the answer fiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and revisions , I added the table insert statements and expected output - @JonArmstrong. Thanks

Comment: Not possible.  Your INSERT statement fails to insert, due to the column mismatch... and your SQL does not produce the "Current result" from the question.  The actual result does not contain rows for 2017, 2019, 2021, but your "Current result" in the question does.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use both `salary` and `maxtemp` in your problem description?  Where is the data for both columns in your `INSERT` statement?  If I were to guess, I believe you're missing `salary` in your `INSERT`, which makes your `SELECT ... AVG(salary) ...` useless.  Please reread all my comments, here and in the answer.  Make sure you address all the issues I raised.

Comment: The "Expected / correct / desired result" is exactly what is now returned, with both sets of data, assuming we're averaging `maxtemp` and we ignore the missing `salary`.  I'm not going to bother to update the answer with the new data, as the data is still questionable.  But with the new data, the answer produces the values (roughly) listed as "Expected result" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The question uses `AVG(salary)` in the SQL example, but your results are averages of the `maxtemp`.  You also never showed any detail about `salary`.  I've corrected that below.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c816052cafa66ba15a45afbfb6dfeb6)

If your database supports this and you have or convert to the correct type, this might do what you wish, by specifying a range of the last 5 years.

Note: I used a date type for the year column.

If your `year` column is an int / numeric type, you can use an expression like `RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

```sql
WITH temp_tbl_2 AS (
        SELECT state
             , wk_number
             , year
             , maxtemp
             , AVG(maxtemp) OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY state, wk_number
                                      ORDER BY year rows 4 PRECEDING
                                ) AS avg_max_5years
          FROM tbl
         ORDER BY state
                , wk_number ASC
                , year ASC
     )
SELECT * FROM temp_tbl_2
;
```

The result:

```
+-------+-----------+------+---------+----------------+
| state | wk_number | year | maxtemp | avg_max_5years |
+-------+-----------+------+---------+----------------+
| A     |         1 | 2015 |   21.00 |      21.000000 |
| A     |         1 | 2016 |   19.30 |      20.150000 |
| A     |         1 | 2017 |   18.00 |      19.433333 |
| A     |         1 | 2018 |   21.40 |      19.925000 |
| A     |         1 | 2019 |   24.80 |      20.900000 |
| A     |         1 | 2020 |   21.70 |      21.040000 |
| A     |         1 | 2021 |   22.50 |      21.680000 |
| A     |         1 | 2022 |   20.10 |      22.100000 |
+-------+-----------+------+---------+----------------+
```

Test case for MySQL 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   state      char(1)
 , wk_number  int
 , year       date
 , maxtemp    decimal(7,2)
 , salary     decimal(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('A',       1,        '2015-01-01',   21  ,   21)
, ('A',       1,        '2016-01-01',   19.3,   20.15)
, ('A',       1,        '2017-01-01',   18  ,   19.43333333)
, ('A',       1,        '2018-01-01',   21.4,   19.925)
, ('A',       1,        '2019-01-01',   24.8,   20.9)
, ('A',       1,        '2020-01-01',   21.7,   21.04)
, ('A',       1,        '2021-01-01',   22.5,   21.68)
, ('A',       1,        '2022-01-01',   20.1,   22.1)
;
```